# How to combine stacks of ammo?

Tags: jagged-alliance-online

In *Jagged Alliance Online*, ammo comes in fairly large stacks, but the slots available for storage are scarce. Is it possible to combine stacks somehow? I’ve tried dragging and dropping one onto another, or putting both incomplete stacks in armory. Right-clicking on a stack also does not do anything.